# How to use raw (r) string when the string is a variable?

Tags: python, string

I use a raw string to deal with backslashes in a place where I specify a directory path:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads'})
```

The code above works.
However, I want to pass the directory path as a variable.

This does not work:

```
pathname_string = 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads'
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'download.default_directory': pathname_string })
```

I get OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\n'

I tried things like:

```
pathname_string = 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads'
(...)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'download.default_directory': r + pathname_string})
```

Or directly using:

```
pathname_string = "'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads'"
pathname_string = "r" + pathname_string 
(...)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'download.default_directory': pathname_string})
```

But these don't seem to work.

Note that the "pathname_string" is a variable that is read from an external source; the directory is not hardcoded.

It is my first time using the "r" prefix for literal strings, so I am a bit lost. Could someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: `pathname_string = r'C:\Downloads'`

Comment: How can one create that same string, if the path part is a preexisting string variable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It looks like you go in circles. i.e. if the path is regular string you already have a problem if backslash is not escaped.

Comment: Raw strings only apply to *literals*, since they involve changing how the literal is parsed. There is no parsing involved for pre-existing values. Once you have a `str` object, it is irrelevant whether it was created from a string literal, a raw string literal, or some other method.

Comment: @buran Please see my comment to chepne's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply define `pathname_string` with with a raw string literal.

```
# exactly equivalent to 'C:\\Downloads'
pathname_string = r'C:\Downloads'

chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs',
    {'download.default_directory': pathname_string}
)
```

If `pathname_string` is read from another source, then there are no literals involved at all, raw or otherwise. It is not your programs responsibility to make sure the correct value is passed to it.

Comment: I see. I think I don't quite understand some things, then, please pardon my ignorance. I am reading the pathname as a variable from a file using `open()` and `line.split()`, and it is of type string. However, if I use it directly in the piece of code, I get the issue: `"[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\n'"`. However, if I hardcode `r 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\n'` then it works fine.